# PHP dividing by 10, adding +1 when result is greater than .0

Tags: php

I am new at programing and I am trying to figure out how to write a variable correctly. To calculate the number for this variable I have to divide by 10 and if the result does not evenly divide, I need to add 1 on to it.

So for example, lets I have to divide 294 / 10, I would get 29.4. In this case I would want to add 1, which would set the variable to 30. But if I was dividing 200 by 10, I would not need to add 1 because it would be an even 20.

So currently I have the variable like this:

```
$total = $count / 10;
```

How would I adjust it to set correctly in cases that it does not even .0

Comment: _I would get 29.4. In this case I would want to add 1, which would set the variable to 30_. No you would get 30.4

Comment: @putvande Your right, I should have said round it up if it is not even

Comment: `echo ceil($count / 10);`

Comment: if u do 255/10 you will get 25.5 so is it for this u need 25.5 to convert to 26 or 30?

Comment: @user2936213 If you read my comment before yours, you can see I said I meant to say round it up

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you're trying to round the value up. There's a built-in function for this purpose -- [`ceil()`](http://php.net/ceil).

From the function description:

> Returns the next highest integer value by rounding up value **if necessary**

Usage:

```
$count = 294;
echo ceil($count / 10); // => 30
```

Answer (score 3):

Make use of [**`ceil()`**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ceil.php) in PHP

```
$count=294;
$total = ceil($count / 10); // your variable $total now holds the value of 30
```

Comment: Why are you using a string for `$count`? Why are you echoing the fact that you're setting the variable?

Comment: I think I asked it wrong, I meant to say round it up, not add one.

Comment: @Robert, I know we are all `clever` , Just making it look like the OP's example.

Comment: yep but echoing assigment may look odd for newbie

Comment: But OP didn't want it echoing anyway

Answer (score 1):

You want to use a function called `ceil`

```
$total = ceil($count / 10);
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ceil.php

Answer (score 0):

```
$total = $count / 10;

if(!is_int($total)) {
    $total = ceil($total);
}
else {
     // if you want to make some actions if number is exactly .0
}
```

Comment: The `if (is_int){...}` is unnecessary code. Ceil returns the next highest integer value by rounding up value if necessary. EDIT: ok you've added else in there. OP didn't require that, they just want the ceil value.

Comment: Nope.. `var_dump( is_int( 10.00 )); //bool(false)`. [**DEMO**](http://codepad.org/0BUlswYq)

Comment: Yes. Added comment for that to avoid next similar question. :)

Comment: Dividing integer by integer returns integer if it "fits" exactly to this integer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **ceil()** function for this.

```
$total = $count / 10;
echo ceil($total);
```

For more details refer http://php.net/ceil

Comment: This has already been suggested [f](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20743302/1438393)[o](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20743300/1438393)[u](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20743289/1438393)[r](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20743319/1438393) times. What does your answer add?

Comment: You can ask other four people also what did they added extra.Its just my view.

Comment: That was soon after the question was asked. But almost 40 minutes has passed since then. My question, is, why do you want to repeat the exact same thing? I don't mean to be rude, but I'm just wondering why you're posting the exact same thing again.